# Retain the selected checkbox during pagination

Tags: checkbox, pagination, salesforce, visualforce, apex

Anyone who have an idea how to retain the selected checkbox during pagination and in selecting another value in selectlist using my codes below. Thank You! :)

Here is the extension I used. It includes the table, selecting values and pagination.

```
 //for season status
public void Stats(){               
    this.RaceEntries= 0;
    this.TotDis= 0;
    this.hasError = false;

    for(TrackWrapper tw : twList){           
            if(tw.isChecked){               
                    if(this.RaceEntries<=12 && this.TotDis<=300){
                        this.RaceEntries++;
                        this.TotDis += tw.tra.Length__c;
                    }

                    if(this.RaceEntries > 12){
                        this.hasError = true;
                        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Race Entries exceeded. 12 tracks per season only.'));
                    }
                    if(this.TotDis > 300){
                        this.hasError = true;
                        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Distance exceeded. 300KM per season only.'));
                    }                                  
              }  

              //List<TrackWrapper> tempList = new List<TrackWrapper>();


    }

    this.RemRace= 12 - this.RaceEntries;
    this.RemDis= 300 - this.TotDis;              
   }

  //Populate the table from the Selected value in selectlist
  public void searchRecords(){
    trackList= new List<Track__c>();
    if( selectValue != null){ //If the selectvalue has a value   
        OffsetSize = 0;                                 
        this.twList= new List<TrackWrapper>(); 
        trackList= Database.query('SELECT Name, Location__c, Difficulty__c, Length__c from Track__c WHERE Difficulty__c LIKE : selectValue LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize');             


        for(Track__c t : this.trackList) {
            TrackWrapper tw = new TrackWrapper();
            tw.tra = t;
            tw.isChecked = false;
            this.twList.add(tw);
            }

        //for TotalPage Numbers per selected value 
        Integer totalSelect = database.countQuery('select count() from Track__c WHERE Difficulty__c LIKE : selectValue');   
        Integer totDiv = totalSelect /5;  
        Integer remain = math.mod(totalSelect, 5);   

          if(remain!= 0){
               this.totalPage = totDiv + 1;                
           } else{
               this.totalPage = totDiv;
           }

           currentPage = 1;                  
           buttonDisable();                

    }else if(selectValue == null){ // If the selectvalue is null                             
        this.twList= new List<TrackWrapper>();
        trackList= Database.query('SELECT Name, Location__c, Difficulty__c, Length__c from Track__c LIMIT :LimitSize OFFSET :OffsetSize');          

        for(Track__c t : this.trackList) {
            TrackWrapper tw = new TrackWrapper();
            tw.tra = t;
            tw.isChecked = false;
            this.twList.add(tw);               
         }               

          //for TotalPage Numbers per selected value 
         Integer total = database.countQuery('select count() from Track__c');  
         Integer tot = total/5;  
         Integer rem = math.mod(total, 5);   

          if(rem!= 0){
                this.totalPage = tot + 1;                
           }else{
               this.totalPage = tot;
           }     
           buttonDisable(); 
    }           
    }         

 //for pagination   
public integer totalRecs;
public integer OffsetSize{get;set;}
public integer LimitSize= 5;    

public boolean isFirstPage {get;set;}
public boolean isLastPage {get;set;}    

public Integer currentPage {get;set;}
public Integer totalPage {get;set;}          
public Integer remainder {get;set;}

public void buttonDisable(){
    this.isFirstPage = false;
    this.isLastPage = false;

    if(currentPage == 1){
        this.isFirstPage = true;
    }

    if(currentPage == totalPage) {
        this.isLastPage = true;
    }  
   }

  // PAGINATION  
   public void FirstPage(){
    OffsetSize = 0;
    searchRecords();   
    this.currentPage = 1;      
    buttonDisable();   
   }      

   public void previous(){
    OffsetSize = OffsetSize - LimitSize;       
    searchRecords(); 
    this.currentPage--;    
    buttonDisable();           
   }

   public void next(){        
    OffsetSize = OffsetSize + LimitSize;      
    searchRecords();
    this.currentPage++;                
    buttonDisable();        
    }  

  public void LastPage(){
    totalRecs = [select count() from track__c];
    OffsetSize = totalrecs - math.mod(totalRecs,LimitSize);
    searchRecords();
    this.currentPage = this.totalPage;
    buttonDisable();     
   }
```

And this is the VisualForce I used. It also includes the table, selectlist, and pagination.

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Season Stats" id="stat">                                                      
            <apex:outputText label="Race Entries" value="{!RaceEntries}" /> 
            <apex:outputText label="Total Distance" value="{!TotDis}"/>
            <apex:outputText label="Remaining Race Entries" value="{!RemRace}"/>
            <apex:outputText label="Remaining Distance" value="{!RemDis}"/>        
        </apex:pageBlockSection>      

        <apex:actionRegion >          
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="details" title="Tracks" columns="1">    
           <apex:outputLabel value="Track Difficulty Level Filter" />         
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectValue}">                 
                    <apex:selectOption itemValue=""  itemLabel="All" />                                               
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!statusOptions}" />                                    
                   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!searchRecords}" rerender="details" status="waitStatus"/>
                </apex:selectList>    

                <apex:outputPanel id="out">
                    <apex:actionStatus id="waitStatus">    
                        <apex:facet name="start">
                            <apex:outputPanel >
                                <apex:outputText >Updating...</apex:outputText>
                                <apex:image value="https://shop.usa.canon.com/estore/marketing/maxify/redesign/maxify-loader.gif" title="Processing..." height="20px"/>         
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:facet>
                    </apex:actionstatus>
                </apex:outputPanel>                          

                <apex:outputPanel ><br/>
                    <apex:pageBlocktable value="{!twList}" var="track" id="table">               
                        <apex:column HeaderValue="Select">                        
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!track.isChecked}">    
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="stat, messages, btnsave" action="{!Stats}" status="waitStatus"/>
                            </apex:inputCheckbox>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column value="{!track.tra.Name}" HeaderValue="Track Name"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!track.tra.Location__c}" HeaderValue="Location"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!track.tra.Difficulty__c}" HeaderValue="Difficulty"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!track.tra.Length__c}" HeaderValue="Circuit Length (KM)"/> 
                 </apex:pageBlocktable>
               </apex:outputPanel>  

       <!-- Pagination -->
           <center>
              <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">  
                 <apex:panelGrid columns="6">                
                      <center>
                       <apex:commandButton value="First Page" rerender="details" action="{!FirstPage}" disabled="{!isFirstPage}" />
                        <apex:commandButton value="Previous" rerender="details" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!isFirstPage}"/>
                        Page {!currentPage} of {!totalPage}
                        <apex:commandButton value="Next" rerender="details" action="{!next}" disabled="{!isLastPage}" />
                        <apex:commandButton value="Last Page" rerender="details" action="{!LastPage}" disabled="{!isLastPage}" /> 
                        </center>
                </apex:panelGrid> 
              </apex:pageBlockSection> 
           </center> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>             
      </apex:actionRegion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Map to store the current values in memory prior to pagination, then, retrieve values back from the map after pagination.  for example:

```
Map<Id,trackWrapper> trackMap = new Map<Id,trackWrapper>();

public next(){
  for ( trackWrapper t : twList ){
    trackMap.put( t.tra.id, t);
  }
  //paginate method
  for ( trackWrapper t : twList ){
    if ( trackMap.containsKey(t.tra.id) ){
      t.isChecked = trackMap.get(t.tra.id).isChecked;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work, can you provide more details?  Did you call your paginate method where the comment "//paginate method" is?